# How to get button to display different video according to the row it is pressed in?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, video, tableview

Currently I have my code setup to where in each table view cell there is a button that displays a video after is pressed. Each table view cell row contains the button (there are x amount of cells) however no matter which row the button is tapped in it always leads to the same video. Is there a way to make to where, depending on the row the button is in, it displays a video? My code only has one video file in it currently but how could I make it to where depending on the cell the button is tapped in, it shows a specific video? For example, if the button is tapped in row one I want it to show a certain video, and the same for two, and three, and so on. Right now they all display the same video.

Here is my code for the table view cell:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class VideoPlayerView: UIView {

    let pauseButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Triangle 2"), for: .normal)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.tintColor = UIColor.white
        button.isHidden = false
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePause), for: .touchUpInside)

        return button
    }()

    var player: AVPlayer?
    var isPlaying = false

    func handlePause() {
        if isPlaying {
            player?.pause()
            pauseButton.alpha = 1.0 }

        else { player?.play()
            pauseButton.alpha = 0.01
        }

        isPlaying = !isPlaying
    }

    //container view that holds sublayers for the video control objects
    let controlsContainerView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 1.0)
        return view
    }()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        //setupPlayerView()

        //configures container view (video's background)
        controlsContainerView.frame = frame
        addSubview(controlsContainerView)
        backgroundColor = UIColor.black


        //following adds pause/play button to video
        controlsContainerView.addSubview(pauseButton)
        pauseButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        pauseButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    //function that sets up video playback
    private func setupPlayerView() {

        //variable that contains video url
        let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/jordanlagrone/Desktop/BlackHeartBB/BlackHeartBB/dunk.mov")

        player = AVPlayer(url: fileUrl)

        //video only renders if you specify 'playerLayer'
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        self.layer.insertSublayer(playerLayer, at: 1)
        playerLayer.frame = frame


        player?.play()


        //attached obeserver of 'player' to tell when 'player' is ready
        player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem.loadedTimeRanges", options: .new, context: nil)

    }

    //method called every time you add obserever to an object
    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        //strring that lets AVPlayer know its ready
        if keyPath == "currentItem.loadedTimeRanges" {

            //configures container view while video is playing
            controlsContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            pauseButton.alpha = 0.05
            isPlaying = true

        }
    }
}
```

---

```
class DrillsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var videoURL:[URL] = [URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/jordanlagrone/Desktop/BlackHeartBB/BlackHeartBB/dunk.mov"), URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/jordanlagrone/Desktop/BlackHeartBB/BlackHeartBB/mk.MOV")]
    var video = URL(fileURLWithPath: String())

    @IBOutlet weak var logoImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var drillTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!

    @IBAction func watchButton(_ sender: Any) {
        print(123)

        //controls video background view
        if let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            let view = UIView(frame: keyWindow.frame)
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

            view.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: keyWindow.frame.width, height: keyWindow.frame.height)

            let videoPlayerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: keyWindow.frame.width, height: keyWindow.frame.width * 9 / 16)
            let videoPlayerView = VideoPlayerView(frame: videoPlayerFrame)
            view.addSubview(videoPlayerView)

            keyWindow.addSubview(view)
            UIView.animate(
                withDuration: 0.5,
                delay: 0,
                options: .curveEaseOut,
                animations: {
                    view.frame = keyWindow.frame

                },
                completion: { completedAnimation in
                    //possible features implemented later
                    UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Code for table view:

```
class DrillsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var arrayForKey2 = [[String]]()
    var keyIndex = Int()
    var headLabel = String()
    var labels = Array(trainingDict.keys)

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: DrillsTableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var drillLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var labelBackground: UIView!


    @IBAction func back(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "back", sender: self)
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arrayForKey2.count
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell" , for: indexPath) as! DrillsTableViewCell
        cell.playButton.tag = indexPath.row


        //clear background color needed in order to display gradient cell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        //gradient configuration
        gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = tableView.bounds
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.darkGray.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor]
        tableView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
        gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)

        //Possible method for 'drillLabel' gradient
        drillLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Symbol", size: 24.0)

        //attributes for watch/play button

        cell.playButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        cell.playButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 2)
        cell.playButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
        cell.playButton.layer.shadowRadius = 1

        //details for cell label display
        cell.borderWidth = 1.5
        cell.borderColor = UIColor.white
        cell.drillTitle.text = "\(arrayForKey2[keyIndex][indexPath.row])"
        cell.drillTitle.font = UIFont(name: "Symbol", size: 18.0)
        cell.drillTitle.textColor = UIColor.white

        return cell
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        drillLabel.text = labels[keyIndex]
    }
}
```

Comment: No one can help if you don't show the relevant table view code and your button handling code.

Comment: This is code for `UIView`, not `UITableViewCell`

Comment: I added the approbate code

Comment: The button you are talking about is playButton?

Comment: Yes that is right

Comment: Can you show the action method of this button?

Comment: its `watchButton`. Idk why I gave them two different names

Comment: Does the answer solve your problem, @Captain Code

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should refactor your code to get required behaviour. Please check the following code:

First make changes in `VideoPlayerView` method named `setupPlayerView` .Replace your implementation with this:

```
func setupPlayerView(for url: URL) {




    player = AVPlayer(url: url)

//video only renders if you specify 'playerLayer'
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    self.layer.insertSublayer(playerLayer, at: 1)
    playerLayer.frame = frame


    player?.play()


    //attached obeserver of 'player' to tell when 'player' is ready
    player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem.loadedTimeRanges", options: .new, context: nil)

  }
```

Now make change in `DrillsTableViewCell` ,make changes in videosURLs and I added a new variable singleVideoURL, your new class will look like this:

```
class DrillsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

   var videoURLs:[URL] = [URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/jordanlagrone/Desktop/BlackHeartBB/BlackHeartBB/dunk.mov"), URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/jordanlagrone/Desktop/BlackHeartBB/BlackHeartBB/mk.MOV")]




  @IBOutlet weak var logoImage: UIImageView!

  @IBOutlet weak var drillTitle: UILabel!


  @IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!
  @IBAction func watchButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
print(123)


    //controls video background view
    if let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
        let view = UIView(frame: keyWindow.frame)
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        var singleVideoURL = videoURLs[sender.tag]

       view.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: keyWindow.frame.width, height: keyWindow.frame.height)

        let videoPlayerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: keyWindow.frame.width, height: keyWindow.frame.width * 9 / 16)
        let videoPlayerView = VideoPlayerView(frame: videoPlayerFrame)
        videoPlayerView .setupPlayerView(for: singleVideoURL)
        view.addSubview(videoPlayerView)


        keyWindow.addSubview(view)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

                view.frame = keyWindow.frame

        }, completion: { (completedAnimation) in
            //possible features implemented later
            UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true


        })



}
```

Comment: This code doesn't accomplish what I'm trying to do. It's quite simple. If the button is tapped in row 1 I want a specific video to play, same for row 2 and row 3 etc. The button should know what row it was pressed in and depending on the row it's in a specific video (associated with that row) should play.

Comment: @CaptainCode Above code will select the url from videoURLs array, say button in row 0 is clicked, in your tableview you are giving the indexPath.row to button.tag, so it will be 0, and when it will come in action method , it will select the video url at 0 index from videoURLs and will play it, isnt that you want? Please correct if I am wrong

Comment: Yes this what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @CaptainCode Have you tried the above code?I think its also doing the same thing, please check

Comment: @CaptainCode Can you tell me what is the error in above code please?

Comment: I get 3 errors. One says `missing argument for parameter in call` at the `setupPlayerView()` line. 2nd error says `Cannot convert value of type string to expected argument type URL`. 3rd one says `Cannot convert value of type URL to expected argument type String`.

Comment: That got rid of two errors!!! one final error reads `missing argument parameter "for" in call`.

Comment: Where are you calling this function?

Comment: Look above in the provided code. In the `override init`. It's called `setupPlayerView()`

Comment: @CaptainCode please comment this line and then run your code, see if it works

Comment: same problem occurring. No matter what row I press button in the same video file plays

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151850/discussion-between-user1000-and-captain-code).

Answer (score 1):

First you have to distinguish the buttons added in the cell by giving them tag value in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method

```
    cell.button.tag = indexpath.row
```

This will set different tag values to the buttons present in each cell.
Then add below to it:

```
    cell.button.addTarget(self, action:(YourController.buttonMethodPlayVideo(:)) , forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Create a method for button to perform action on click:

```
    func buttonMethodPlayVideo(sender: UIButton) {
     print(sender.tag)
   }
```

In above method when you will click on button you will get different tag values.
According to that value you can play different videos or pass different video name to player to play vudeo.

Comment: Thank you, haven't implemented the code yet but this is very clear and seems applicable! Trying it now...

Comment: I've added more code to help better explain my question. Does that change the solution to my problem any?

Comment: Where would I put the `buttonMethodPlayVideo` method at in my code?

Comment: In table view controller or view controller where you have added tableview

Answer (score 0):

Setup an array to put your videos' paths into, and its indexe should match the index of the cell. In addition, you can pass the row number of the cell to the button inside as its tag. So when you tap on that button, you can find a specific video path in the array through the button's tag.