# How to get button to play different videos depending on the row it's in?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, video, cell

I have a table view with a custom cell that contains a button. Depending on the row the button is selected in, I want a specific video file to play. However right now the way my code is setup is no matter what row the button is pressed in it shows the same video file. How could I configure my code to make sure each row shows a different video of my liking?

Code for table view:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

class DrillsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var player: AVPlayer?
var arrayForKey2 = [[String]]()
var keyIndex = Int()
var headLabel = String()
var labels = Array(trainingDict.keys)

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: DrillsTableView!

@IBOutlet weak var drillLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var labelBackground: UIView!


@IBAction func back(_ sender: Any) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "back", sender: self)
}



public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{

    return arrayForKey2.count
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell" , for: indexPath) as! DrillsTableViewCell



    //clear background color needed in order to display gradient cell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    //gradient configuration
    gradient = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.frame = tableView.bounds
    gradient.colors = [UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.darkGray.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor]
    tableView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)





//Possible method for 'drillLabel' gradient
    //drillLabelGradient = CAGradientLayer()
    //drillLabelGradient.frame = labelBackground.bounds
    //drillLabelGradient.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.darkGray.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor]
    //labelBackground.layer.insertSublayer(drillLabelGradient, at: 0)
    //drillLabelGradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    //drillLabelGradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    drillLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Symbol", size: 24.0)

    //attributes for watch/play button

    cell.playButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    cell.playButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 2)
    cell.playButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7
    cell.playButton.layer.shadowRadius = 1

    //details for cell label display
    cell.borderWidth = 1.5
    cell.borderColor = UIColor.white
    cell.drillTitle.text = "\(arrayForKey2[keyIndex][indexPath.row])"
    cell.drillTitle.font = UIFont(name: "Symbol", size: 18.0)
    cell.drillTitle.textColor = UIColor.white

    return cell
}




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    drillLabel.text = labels[keyIndex]

       }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


 }
```

Code for table view cell:

```
   import UIKit
  import AVFoundation
  import AVKit

  class VideoPlayerView: UIView {

let pauseButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Triangle 2"), for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.tintColor = UIColor.white
    button.isHidden = false
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePause), for: .touchUpInside)

    return button
}()

var isPlaying = false

func handlePause() {
    if isPlaying {
        player?.pause()
    pauseButton.alpha = 1.0 }

    else { player?.play()
        pauseButton.alpha = 0.01
    }

    isPlaying = !isPlaying
}

//container view that holds sublayers for the video control objects
let controlsContainerView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 1.0)
    return view
}()


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    setupPlayerView()

    //configures container view (video's background)
    controlsContainerView.frame = frame
    addSubview(controlsContainerView)
    backgroundColor = UIColor.black


    //following adds pause/play button to video
    controlsContainerView.addSubview(pauseButton)
    pauseButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    pauseButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true


}

var player: AVPlayer?

//function that sets up video playback
private func setupPlayerView() {



    //variable that contains video url
    let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/jordanlagrone/Desktop/BlackHeartBB/BlackHeartBB/dunk.mov")




        player = AVPlayer(url: fileUrl)

    //video only renders if you specify 'playerLayer'
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        self.layer.insertSublayer(playerLayer, at: 1)
        playerLayer.frame = frame


        player?.play()


        //attached obeserver of 'player' to tell when 'player' is ready
        player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem.loadedTimeRanges", options: .new, context: nil)

}
//method called every time you add obserever to an object
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    //strring that lets AVPlayer know its ready
    if keyPath == "currentItem.loadedTimeRanges" {

        //configures container view while video is playing
        controlsContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        pauseButton.alpha = 0.05
        isPlaying = true

    }
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

```
 class DrillsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var videoURL:[URL] = [URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/jordanlagrone/Desktop/BlackHeartBB/BlackHeartBB/dunk.mov"), URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/jordanlagrone/Desktop/BlackHeartBB/BlackHeartBB/mk.MOV")]
var video = URL(fileURLWithPath: String())


@IBOutlet weak var logoImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var drillTitle: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!
@IBAction func watchButton(_ sender: Any) {
    print(123)


        //controls video background view
        if let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            let view = UIView(frame: keyWindow.frame)
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white


           view.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: keyWindow.frame.width, height: keyWindow.frame.height)

            let videoPlayerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: keyWindow.frame.width, height: keyWindow.frame.width * 9 / 16)
            let videoPlayerView = VideoPlayerView(frame: videoPlayerFrame)
            view.addSubview(videoPlayerView)


            keyWindow.addSubview(view)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

                    view.frame = keyWindow.frame

            }, completion: { (completedAnimation) in
                //possible features implemented later
                UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true


            })



    }

}
```

}

Comment: Define a property in your cell called lets say `videoUrl`and in your cellForRow method pass the url correspondent to indexpath

Comment: Could you give an example using code? Your explanation is too vague for a beginner like me to comprehend off the bat

Comment: I am a little confused about your question, that is why don´t answer, you need to play a different video url in each cell? and your urls are in your ViewController? please clarify me those questions and I will provide an answer

Comment: YES! Each time a button is pressed, depending on the row its in, a corresponding video should play that associated with that row.

Comment: My url's are in `VideoPlayerView` class. It's in the code above

Comment: So WHY and/or HOW is this question different from the one you asked less than a day ago? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45658094/how-to-get-button-to-display-different-video-according-to-the-row-it-is-pressed) It looks to me like you should edit that question.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to add in your `VideoPlayerView` class a var with the url you will play in your class

```
fileprivate var videoUrl : URL?
```

and modify your `VideoPlayerView` `setupPlayerView` method to pass url something like this

```
private func setupPlayerView(url:URL)
```

**After that you need replace this lines in `DrillsTableViewCell`**

```
var videoURL:[URL] = [URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/jordanlagrone/Desktop/BlackHeartBB/BlackHeartBB/dunk.mov"), URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/jordanlagrone/Desktop/BlackHeartBB/BlackHeartBB/mk.MOV")]
var video = URL(fileURLWithPath: String())
```

by this one

```
var videoURL:URL?
```

**and in your `watchButton` action you need to add**

```
videoPlayerView.setupPlayerView(self.videoURL!)
```

**After that you will be able to add this line in your cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
if let urlValid = URL(string: arrayForKey2[indexPath.row].first)
{
cell.videoURL = urlValid
}
```

After that your app must work

**Full Code VideoPlayerView**

```
  import UIKit
  import AVFoundation
  import AVKit

  class VideoPlayerView: UIView {

  fileprivate var videoUrl : URL?

let pauseButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Triangle 2"), for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.tintColor = UIColor.white
    button.isHidden = false
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handlePause), for: .touchUpInside)

    return button
}()

var isPlaying = false

func handlePause() {
    if isPlaying {
        player?.pause()
    pauseButton.alpha = 1.0 }

    else { player?.play()
        pauseButton.alpha = 0.01
    }

    isPlaying = !isPlaying
}

//container view that holds sublayers for the video control objects
let controlsContainerView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 1.0)
    return view
}()


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    setupPlayerView()

    //configures container view (video's background)
    controlsContainerView.frame = frame
    addSubview(controlsContainerView)
    backgroundColor = UIColor.black


    //following adds pause/play button to video
    controlsContainerView.addSubview(pauseButton)
    pauseButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    pauseButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true


}

var player: AVPlayer?

//function that sets up video playback
private func setupPlayerView(url:URL) {
    //variable that contains video url
    self.videoUrl = url

    player = AVPlayer(url: self.videoUrl)

    //video only renders if you specify 'playerLayer'
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        self.layer.insertSublayer(playerLayer, at: 1)
        playerLayer.frame = frame


        player?.play()


        //attached obeserver of 'player' to tell when 'player' is ready
        player?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem.loadedTimeRanges", options: .new, context: nil)

}
//method called every time you add obserever to an object
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    //strring that lets AVPlayer know its ready
    if keyPath == "currentItem.loadedTimeRanges" {

        //configures container view while video is playing
        controlsContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        pauseButton.alpha = 0.05
        isPlaying = true

    }
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}
```

**Full Code DrillsTableViewCell**

```
class DrillsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var videoURL:URL?

@IBOutlet weak var logoImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var drillTitle: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var playButton: UIButton!
@IBAction func watchButton(_ sender: Any) {
    print(123)
       guard self.videoURL != nil else{
             return
        }

        //controls video background view
        if let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
            let view = UIView(frame: keyWindow.frame)
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white


           view.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: keyWindow.frame.width, height: keyWindow.frame.height)

            let videoPlayerFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: keyWindow.frame.width, height: keyWindow.frame.width * 9 / 16)
            let videoPlayerView = VideoPlayerView(frame: videoPlayerFrame)
            videoPlayerView.setupPlayerView(self.videoURL!) //added
            view.addSubview(videoPlayerView)


            keyWindow.addSubview(view)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

                    view.frame = keyWindow.frame

            }, completion: { (completedAnimation) in
                //possible features implemented later
                UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true


            })



    }

}
```

This code was not tested so if have some issues let me know
Hope this helps